# Determine the language from the node?

Tags: 7, nodes, i18n-l10n

At `admin/config/regional/language/configure` there are several options:

- URL   - Determine the language from the URL
- Session   - Determine the language from a request/session parameter.
- User  -  Follow the user's language preference.
- Browser -     Determine the language from the browser's language settings.
- Default   - Use the default site language (English).

I don't want to use a language prefix or even different domains. I just want a very flat URL structure.

So I want the language to mainly depend on the current node. Is there a way to do that?

I want to avoid node translation. So each node will only be in one language only.

Comment: What selection method will you use to determine the user's language preference (so that the correct content can be loaded)?

Comment: At first I didn't understand your comment, updated the question accordingly. I'm not a fan of Drupal's content translation system (at least in 6 and 7). But if there's no good solution here I'll probably start using it anyway on this specific site.

Comment: Forgive me if this is over-simplifying things: if you don't need language switching, and each node is going to be in a single language, why does the site need to be multilingual at all? Aren't you just describing a standard Drupal site whose nodes happen to have content in varying languages?

Comment: I thought of keeping it even simpler, to use categories for languages but I want menus and views that use the language of the content.